# Format value in XAML with a decimal separator?

Tags: wpf, xaml, formatting, numbers

I have a little problem formatting double values in my XAML code.

```
double price = 10300.455;
```

This number should be displayed as **10,300.45** on US systems and as **10.300,45** on German systems.

So far I managed to limit the numbers with the following.

```
Binding="{Binding price, StringFormat=F2}"
```

But the result is **10300.45** and that is not what I had in mind. I could fix this easily using a converter, but I don't want to do that if there is another way around. Just the right Formatter would be fine.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
Binding="{Binding price, StringFormat=N2}"
```

Try `N` instead of `F`. `N` is number format, which based on different cultures, automatically displays number formatting. Look at the sample code below which is a console application. However, if binding uses correct culture, you will get the correct value. `F2` is fixed point notation.

```
    double price = 10300.455;

    Console.WriteLine(price.ToString("N2", 
        CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE") ));
    // displays 10.300,46

    Console.WriteLine(price.ToString("N2",
        CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US") ));
    // displays 10,300.46
```

Answer (score 5):

For anyone wondering information regarding the different build in string formats and their usages can be seen here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Set current system culture as global WPF culture.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/442505/WPF-default-binding-format-culture

```cs
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(FrameworkElement),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```